# what is accessTokenValue, tokenSecretValue in linkedin-j?

Tags: java

I try to connect with linkedin using linkedin-j api.

we get consumerKeyValue, consumerSecretValue when we register in for application in linked in how to get ccessTokenValue, tokenSecretValue.

following are two lines where we user ccessTokenValue, tokenSecretValue.

```
final LinkedInApiClientFactory factory = LinkedInApiClientFactory.newInstance(consumerKeyValue, consumerSecretValue);

final LinkedInApiClient client = factory.createLinkedInApiClient(accessTokenValue, tokenSecretValue);
```